# Android AlertDialog how to block second click on the ok button?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Example:

```
System.out.println("in!");
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setMessage("test!!!");
    dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, 
        new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                System.out.println("Only one click!");
            }
    });
    dialog.show();
```

Out:
in!
in!
Only one click!
Only one click!
Only one click!
Only one click!

Comment: You want to disable the button after first click or what?

Comment: I want to make imposible second click at all.

Comment: This is bad by design, Dialogs aren't supposed to behave this way...

Comment: why can't you dismiss the dialog when positive button is clicked? in onClick(), add "dialog.dismiss()" is all you need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the button (positive) and set enabled to false.

```
System.out.println("in!");
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
dialog.setMessage("test!!!");
dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, 
    new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // disable on 1st click;
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = (AlertDialog)dialog;
            alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
            System.out.println("Only one click!");
        }
});
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 2):

What i don't understand is why someone could click a second time on an alertdialog, because teh buttons are supposed to close the dialog after performing some action.
Why do you not close the dialog with
    dialog.dismiss()
 ?

Comment: The action can get queued before the dialog is actually dismissed. If you do any operation that takes even a small amount of time you can hit the button a second time before the dismiss actually occurs which will trigger a second callback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable it. I recommend a flag, which must be stored at the class level.

```
Boolean hasBeenClicked=false;


System.out.println("in!");
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setMessage("test!!!");
    dialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, 
        new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (!hasBeenClicked)
                {
                  hasBeenClicked=true;
                  System.out.println("Only one click!");
                }
            }
    });
    dialog.show();
```